# Why does my phone show 2 connected devices when I use the hotspot on my Android phone?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, xiaomi

My Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro show 2 connected devices when I use the hotspot on my Android phone. One is my own laptop, and the other is `192.168.43.1`. I know that this is the default gateway for most wireless routers, but how is it possible for my phone to connect to the network that it's creating and sharing by itself?

I tried searching for the answer on the web, but couldn't find it. Could you please help me and explain why is that the case?